# Error in binary file while adding permission

Tags: blackberry, permissions, momentics

I am a newbie in blackberry, trying to build a application in native cascade c++. 
I am using Momentics IDE and sdk(10.3.1). In my helloworld application I try to use the persmission by looking at the official document of blackberry
https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/core/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.devguide/topic/c_about_bar_app_descriptor_file.html 
But I am getting error while running the app. I am using the simulator.
My error message

```
Error in final launch sequence
Cannot prepare and download the binary
Error: Could not obtain launch permissions
```

Please help me out.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a silly mistake: I figure it out that i have to run the simulator with "Run as Administration" and after it just have to give access the permission from the simulator.